# Tomcat Context-Params ignored in Spring webapp when using PropertyPlaceholder

Tags: spring

I was previously using, the now deprecated, class `org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to load a properties file from the server's filesystem. I had the following bean definied:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="${config}"/>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="searchContextAttributes" value="true"/>
    <property name="contextOverride" value="false"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

The `config` is an argument that is passed when starting Tomcat, i.e.

```
-Dconfig=/path/to/application.properties
```

For the webapp I also have a context file:

```
<Context docBase="/path/to/application.war">
    <Parameter name="host" value="localhost" override="false"/>
    <Parameter name="port" value="8080" override="false"/>
</Context>
```

If the `.properties` file, specified by the `-Dconfig` argument, contains the property that some other bean references then the value from the `.properties` file is used, otherwise the value from the the context xml file is used.

This allowed me to have a set of default properties deployed with the WAR and if required, I was able to specify a `.properties` file to override particular values.

Now, I'm updating to use the new property abstractions in Spring 3.1 but I can't seem to figure out what the equivalent approach to this is?

I have the same context file and war deployed in the same way, and I now have the following in the application:

```
<context:property-placeholder
        location="${config}"
        system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"
        ignore-resource-not-found="true"
        ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

This finds and uses the properties from the properties file, BUT it does not use the values from the context XML file.

How do I get my application to use the context params when using this new property-placeholder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarise the problem is that the Context Parameters from the servlet context file were not being used to resolve placeholders when using the new Property Placeholder namespace introduced in Spring 3.1.

I have figured out a solution, with the following

```
<context:property-placeholder location="${config}" local-override="true" ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>
```

I can specify one or more *.properties files on the local filesystem using a JVM arg, eg:

```
-Dconfig=/path/app.properties
```

If a placeholder property cannot be resolved after checking the `app.properties` file then the Servlet Context Parameters are checked.

This allows me to have default values using context params in a the web.xml and where I need to I can override these values by specifying the location of *.properties files using the `config` JVM arg.

The key to getting it to work this way was to include `local-override="true"`, which is false by default. I'm not fully sure that it makes sense, since the description for that attribute is:

> Specifies whether local properties override properties from files. Default
>       is "false": Properties from files override local defaults.

If the same property key exists in the `app.properties` and the `web.xml` the value from the `app.properties` is used.

Answer (score 1):

Spring uses a default property file unless the user-based property file is defined. If you want to control .properties file, please follow the instructions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214862/propertyplaceholder-in-spring).

If you want to take advantage of application.properties there are two ways to do it.

```
<!-- allows for ${} replacement in the spring xml configuration from the 
    system.properties file on the classpath -->
<util:properties id="appProperties" location="classpath:application.properties"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>
```

util tag lets you to use a Property class to read the properties across your application. For example:

```
@Autowired
public MyPropertyReader(Properties appProperties) {
    String prop1 =  appProperties.getProperty("my.address");
    String prop2 =  appProperties.getProperty("my.version");
}
```

If you want to use the values within your context file use the context:property-placeholder tag. Then you can use your values as

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" p:brokerURL="${jms.primary.server}"/>
```

where for example jms.primary.server=172.168.10.18:6161 in application.properties.

Comment: I don't think you've fully understood my original post. I have the placeholders resolved using properties file already. The question asks about using Context Parameters.

Comment: Have you followed the link from the 1st sentence? The rest of the answer is just an add-on for other developers that use .properties and application.properties.

Comment: The issue is about Context Parameters - not properties files.