# System property suffix for use in PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring

I having problems defining database properties in different environments. The properties file looks like this:

```
db.url-DEV=host1:port:con...
db.user-DEV=user1

db.url-PROD=host2:port:con...
db.user-PROD=user2
```

The suffixes (-DEV,-PROD) are set on server side using a system property. How may I configure my PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to check for a system property to switch to the right configuration? There has to be a default value if a system property is not set.

I have tried something like this, but that did not work:

```
${#{'db.url'+${systemEnvironmentVar}}}
```

The PropertyConfigurer says 'property with name 'db.url'+${systemEnvironmentVar} not found.

Comment: Check out Spring profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use nested expression, example from real project:

```
<property name="username" value="${${ENV_NAME}database.username}" />
<property name="password" value="${${ENV_NAME}database.password}" />
```

where ENV_NAME is system property. Note that you have to declare this variable in jvm parameters. You can also add default ENV_NAME to your properties:

```
ENV_NAME=dev
```

And configure propertyPlaceholder to override with system properties:

```
<property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
<property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
```

more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214862/propertyplaceholder-in-spring)

But you can also use [spring profiles](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-spring-profiles-xml)

Answer (score 0):

Create two properties files `dev.properties` and `prod.properties` with content

```
db.url=host1:port:con...
db.user=user1
```

This is common Spring pattern.